# Count ajax call in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have one main checkbox, with name Select All. What I want to do is once user click on that checkbox then loader will be displayed, it is working fine.

Now once user click on select all checkbox so it will get selected other checkboxes as well as call Ajax method for each checkbox selection.

Now what I want is I want to know either total Ajax call OR I want to know when last Ajax call completed. So I can put condition in that last ajax call and hide that loader

I am getting below response once we click on select all checkbox, you can see below image for that.

I have tried to add one array in success function and push response in it, but every time that array length come as 1. Below is code

```
var AjaxCall = [];

success: function (response) {
                if (response.isSuccess) {
                    console.log(response);
                    AjaxCall.push(response.id);
                    $("#loading").hide();
                }
                else {
                      //show some error
                }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUSJL.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Lapskaus I have added some code..let me know if you want to see more so I can share that also.

Comment: If the length of the array `AjaxCall` is always 1 after pushing a `response.id` into it,i guess it is a scope issue. The variable `var AjaxCall = [];` needs to be accessible for all of your ajax calls and can not be local to those calls.

Comment: I have added that before Ajax call like this, so is that ok OR need to define that outside of function.    var AjaxCall = [];           $("#loading").show();         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

Comment: If you declare it within a function, it's scope is limited to that function.

Comment: is there any way I can know this is last ajax call completed from loop

Comment: Option 1) don't send 100s of ajax requests at the same time.  In fact, there is no option 2.

Comment: Either change your end point or add a second one to allow an array, or have another end point for "all" that does the work for you.   You could also implement an ajax queue which will only send the next request when the first one finishes.

Comment: If you must continue down this route, then use `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()` to determine when your ajax calls start/stop:  See [Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) there's also [this page on learn jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ajax-events/).

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea for `click on select all checkbox so it will get selected other checkboxes as well as call Ajax method for each checkbox selection`. Is there some possibilities to change this kind of logic? I mean add a submit button to send all the selected options data to the backend should be better.

Comment: And if you insist on it, you may add a method which listening the select all action, first you can check how many options are selected this time, and set the count to a global variable. Then each callback method in ajax call should subtract this number by one, and check if the variable==0, if it equals 0, that means all ajax done. But it really not a good choice. I prefer to submit all the data together, so that one ajax request is enough.